# cypress: condition with label and css locator

Tags: cypress

How would you do something like this:
I have this:

```
<label><input type="checkbox">TEXT TO FIND</label>
```

and it is in a condition where I would like to find out if it exists with a certain label (TEXT TO FIND):

```
...
} else if (edit.find('label input[type="checkbox"]').text() === 'TEXT TO FIND') {
```

unfortunately above does not work, hence the question... I think the problem is that the "TEXT TO FIND" is on the level of  but it looks on . But I need to define the input tag.

[the 'edit comes from this: cy.get('body ...').then((edit)=>{ *here the conditions* })   ]

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `input[type="checkbox"]` is inside the label, you can add `:has()` to the CSS selector

```js
edit.find('label:has(input[type="checkbox"])').text() === 'TEXT TO FIND'
```

This keeps the `<label>` as subject so you can check it's text.

You may want to change `.text() === 'TEXT TO FIND'` to `.text().includes('TEXT TO FIND')` or `.text().trim() === 'TEXT TO FIND'` in case of whitespace.

---

#### Do conditional test as late as possible

A better pattern is to make the `if()` test as late as possible, so that you can get some retry on the elements.

```js
cy.get('label:has(input[type="checkbox"])')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => {
    if (text.trim() === 'TEXT TO FIND') {
      ...
```